# Workflow Start Option

Tags: designer-workflow

When I create a new workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 it only shows the Start Workflow Manually in the Start Option.  I can't get it to show me the Start Workflow automatically when new item created or Start workflow automatically when a item is changed.
What do I need to do to get it to show all three options to select from like in 2010?

Answer (score 1):

I think you choose to create a **Site workflow** , in that workflow type you'll have `"Allow this workflow to be manually started"`  as the only start option available , `"Start workflow automatically when an item is created"` and `"Start workflow automatically when an item is changed"` start options are available on the **List workflow**.